# How to pass an additional argument to useSelector

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am calling `useSelector` successfully from a component, which derives a product name from an id.

```
const productId = 25; // whatever

const productName = useSelector(
  (state) =>
    state.dashboard.dashboards.filter(
      ({ Id }) => Id === productId
    )[0].Name
);
```

However, my selector is dependent on `productId`, which I'm storing in a variable in the same file. I'd like to store this `useSelector` call in an external file so it can be shared. I tried the following, but `id` is `undefined`:

**selectors.js**

```js
export const getProductNameById = (store, id) => {
  return store.dashboard.dashboards.filter(({ Id }) => Id === id)[0]
    .Name;
}
```

**some_file.js**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductNameById } from "./selectors";

const productId = 25;
const productName = useSelector(getProductNameById, productId);
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

unfortunately, `selector` function accepts only store's state as argument. I would consider to use a currying approach to tackle the issue:

```
export const getProductNameById = id => store => {
  return store.dashboard.dashboards.filter(({ Id }) => Id === id)[0]
    .Name;
}
```

**some file**

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProductNameById } from "./selectors";

const productId = 25;
const productName = useSelector(getProductNameById(productId));
```

Answer (score 53):

Seems like the way to do this would be like this:

```
const productName = useSelector((state) => getProductNameById(state, productId));
```

This is the how redux docs tutorial seems to handle this.
[here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#what-youve-learned)

Answer (score -4):

This should also work:

```
const productName = useSelector(getProductNameById(productId));
```